# Create Formula Column

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have 3 columns like

- Team Name
- Number of Hours
- Number of Transactions

I have to apply formula like

- TEAM1 – 500 transactions per 8.5 hours  --> 100 % Expection Meet
- TEAM2 – 350 transactions per 8.5 hours  --> 100 % Expection Meet
- TEAM3 – 500 transactions per 8.5 hours  --> 100 % Expection Meet
- TEAM4 – 110 per 8.5 hours               --> 100 % Expection Meet

And if it goes less than the range it is "BELOW Expectation"
and if it is more than "Above Expectation"

I could write logic for one condition only, but not getting how to do it for everything

```
=IF(AND([Number of Hours]=8.5,[Number of Transactions]>550),"OK","Not OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to develop a layered IF statement, something like:

```
=IF(AND(x=y,y<z),"OK",IF(AND( . . .),"OK","Not OK"))
```

However, in this case I would be tempted to simplify it if possible.  Are your expectations based on a standard transaction rate for each team?  If so do we need to be testing for Team Number as well?

I was thinking of a new calculated column Transaction Rate where:

```
=[Number of Transactions] / [Number of Hours]
```

You then have a much simpler nested IF statement:

```
=IF([Transaction Rate] > 80, "OK", IF([Transaction Rate] > 60, "OK", "Not OK"))
```

You will obviously need to set your own trigger points and can add up to 7 nested IF statements as needed.

Comment: I have used this logic but it is showing as incorrect    =IF(AND(logic="PBR",[Transaction Rate]>65),"110",IF(AND(logic="PBR",[Transaction Rate]=65),"100"),IF(AND(logic="PBR",[Transaction Rate]<65),"99.9","Not Ok"))

Comment: Is the Transaction Rate value correct?  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Your formula also looks wrong - your first IF clause is setting the value to 110, your second setting it to 100 but then you have a closing bracket.